# apache superset query error on datetime with timezone column

Tags: apache-superset, meltano

I have a table with a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and I try to simply `SELECT * FROM table`, but I get this message:

> postgresql error: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'`

Am I entering the data incorrectly?

```
creation_datetime = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

...


new_record = {
              "key": valid_value.contract.symbol.lower(),
              "datetime_downloaded_from_api": creation_datetime
             }

yield new_record
```

I use meltano and a singer custom TAP to retrieve and input the data.. meltano taps `streams.py` has the part where I describe the data columns and did this

```
    schema = th.PropertiesList(
        th.Property("datetime_downloaded_from_api", th.DateTimeType),
        th.Property("contract_id", th.IntegerType)
    ).to_dict()
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when you're "exploring" the physical dataset in Superset?

Comment: @Jeremy I posted the fix, which I got from their slack channel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

turned out I needed a specific version of a python library to be installed

```
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
```

Comment: Could you share why did you need that specific version?

Comment: this was a bug or .. something to do with apache-superset.. if you don't do this.. queries in time datetime related areas don't work.. as alluded in my post.  I got this fix from their slack channel

Comment: Some more context on the issue: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/15768